# Looking for a norm to make this functional set a Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Define this set $\mathcal Q$ of functions as follow

$$\mathcal Q = \{Q:[0,1] \rightarrow \overline {\mathbb R} : Q \text{ is càglàd on ]0,1[, } Q(a) \leq Q(b) \, \forall a<b \in [0,1], Q(0) = -\infty,  \int_0^1 |Q(x)| \, dx < \infty \}$$

càglàd means left-continuous, right limits (LCRL). How can one find a norm to equip this space with such that it becomes a Banach space (so Cauchy sequences in $\mathcal Q$ should be converging in $\mathcal Q$ for that norm) ?

The obvious idea is the $L^1([0,1])$ norm, but that does not work ($\mathcal Q$ should be closed in $L^1([0,1]$) for that to work).